# How to deal with http response type in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I write a http get request:

```
  getProduct(path, opts?): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.get(path, opts?.httpParams).pipe(
      map((res:IProduct) => new Product(res))
    );
  }
```

My Product class construct with a Interface:

```
export Interface IProduct {
  productName:string;
  productCode:string;
  descr:string;
}
```

I thought when I assign a interface as type in map() , it will have a check about the content of the response. If it miss some property it will give me a error or something.
But it doesn't, It just pass everything to try to instance a Product Object.

Am I missunderstanding about the usage of Interface? How can I ensure the response match the Interface or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, nothing about your declared typing serves, or even can serve, as a check on the integrity of the data you receive, or how well it matches the interfaces or classes you define.

TypeScript's typing is purely a compile-time feature to help you write more consistent code, and to make things like IntelliSense much smarter and more useful. You'll have to explicitly check the responses yourself if you want to make sure you're getting valid data.